# Android library project some class id in R.java mismatch

Tags: android, android-library

I have 2 projects A and B. I have set project A as a library project and I have added its dependency in project B. Now when I build my Project B, I find that R.java includes id's of controls/layouts from both A and B.

Now I compare the R.java files of project A and B. Initially the class id of say a particular widget is same in both R.java files.
Now I add a new control (say a Button) in Project B. If I check the R.java files now, then there is a mismatch between the class ids of same widget in Project A and B.

Due to this I am getting `classNotfound` and `classcastexception` at runtime. Has anyone faced a similar issue? Its very frustrating!

Comment: Once delete R file in project B. Then clean and rebuild.

Comment: Yes i tried. but still the i am getting same issue. I also tried renaming the widget whose id did not match. But still no difference.

Comment: Once delete R file in A project. Recently I have same problem but not exactly same.

Comment: Tried that also. Still the ids dont match.